# CanInsertFeedSystemFields?

Tags: deployment, permission-sets

Trying to deploy to an Org I get this:

permissionsets/Our_Administrator.permissionset -- Error: Unknown user permission: CanInsertFeedSystemFields

I've figured out that the kind of settings an Org will accept depend whether or not a feature is enabled.

So what does CanInsertFeedSystemFields correspond to, and how can I switch it on or off.

Comment: I have seen this happen before when SFDC doesn't properly provision new feature permissions into all of your orgs (PROD, sandbox1, sandbox2, ...). I had to call SFDC Support where they run a job to sync up the profile's permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission CanInsertFeedSystemFields allows a profile user to set the Author and Created date fields on a chatter post.

In order for this to be accepted metadata in your profile or permission set you must have chatter enabled in the target org.