# While moving custom profiles using eclipse from dev org to partner org found following errors

Tags: profile, eclipse, data-migration, custom-profile

> Unknown user permission: CanInsertFeedSystemFields
>
> Unknown user permission: ChatterInternalUser

What could be the possible solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68946/caninsertfeedsystemfields

Comment: @Ratan After enabling it is showing the second error.

Comment: what is the second error?? @Venky

Comment: @DOMINICEDWARD Unknown user permission: ChatterInternalUser

Answer (score 0):

I guess permission "CanInsertFeedSystemFields" and "ChatterInternalUser" can not be accessed in partner org.
The solution is that you can edit custom profiles with text editor and remove these two items, then try to deploy profiles again.

By the ways, there is a new salesforce IDE named [Metaforce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/metaforce/hhnkaakhlhngcdckdiogpkjihnmgodep?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon). You can try to deploy changes by it. You can install this tool in chrome web store.